# How to create a lazy-evaluated range from a file?

Tags: file-io, d

The File I/O API in Phobos is relatively easy to use, but right now I feel like it's not very well integrated with D's range interface.

I could create a range delimiting the full contents by reading the entire file into an array:

```
import std.file;
auto mydata = cast(ubyte[]) read("filename");
processData(mydata); // takes a range of ubytes
```

But this eager evaluation of the data might be undesired if I only want to retrieve a file's header, for example. The `upTo` parameter doesn't solve this issue if the file's format assumes a variable-length header or any other element we wish to retrieve. It could even be in the middle of the file, and `read` forces me to read all of the file up to that point.

But indeed, there are alternatives. `readf`, `readln`, `byLine` and most particularly `byChunk` let me retrieve pieces of data until I reach the end of the file, or just when I want to stop reading the file.

```
import std.stdio;
File file("filename");
auto chunkRange = file.byChunk(1000); // a range of ubyte[]s
processData(chunkRange); // oops! not expecting chunks!
```

But now I have introduced the complexity of dealing with fixed size chunks of data, rather than a continuous range of bytes.

So how can I create a simple input range of bytes from a file that is lazy evaluated, either by characters or by small chunks (to reduce the number of reads)? Can the range in the second example be seamlessly encapsulated in a way that the data can be processed like in the first example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`std.algorithm.joiner`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#.joiner):

```
auto r = File("test.txt").byChunk(4096).joiner();
```

Note that `byChunk` reuses the same buffer for each chunk, so you may need to add `.map!(chunk => chunk.idup)` to lazily copy the chunks to the heap.

Comment: That seems to work without mapping each chunk to its own memory space. After all, an `InputRange` already expects sequential one-time reading only. Can you think of a case where that is really needed?

Comment: Perhaps it is never needed as you say.